# Converting a dataframe in pandas to another one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logistic-regression

I have loaded a csv "Body Count dataset" from https://figshare.com/articles/On_screen_movie_kill_counts_for_hundreds_of_films/889719 as a data frame to my jupyter notebook.
 My task is to do linear regression in order to predict movies MPAA rating. I have heard, that my data vector X should contain columns: Body_Count, IsAction, IsThriller, and so on...
Unfortunately, I have no idea, how could I get those statistics from my dataset, as every film genre is labeled like "thriller|action|drama".
Do you have any ideas how it could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
genres = df.Genre.str.split('|', expand=True)
```

to create new columns for the various genre types. Then combine this with your data and use `pd.get_dummies()` with `.sum()`:

```
df = pd.concat([df.drop('Genre', axis=1), genres], axis=1)
df = df.set_index(['Film', 'Year', 'Body_Count', 'MPAA_Rating', 'Director', 'Length_Minutes', 'IMDB_Rating']).stack().reset_index(-1, drop=True)
df.columns = ['Genre']

df = pd.get_dummies(df).groupby(level=['Film', 'Body_Count']).sum()
df.head()

                                 Fantasy   ...     Horror  Music  Musical  \
Film                 Body_Count            ...                              
24 Hour Party People 7               0.0   ...        0.0    1.0      0.0   
28 Days Later        53              0.0   ...        1.0    0.0      0.0   
28 Weeks Later       212             0.0   ...        1.0    0.0      0.0   
30 Days of Night     67              0.0   ...        1.0    0.0      0.0   
300                  600             1.0   ...        0.0    0.0      0.0   

                                 Mystery  Romance  Sci-Fi  Sport  Thriller  \
Film                 Body_Count                                              
24 Hour Party People 7               0.0      0.0     0.0    0.0       0.0   
28 Days Later        53              0.0      0.0     1.0    0.0       1.0   
28 Weeks Later       212             0.0      0.0     1.0    0.0       1.0   
30 Days of Night     67              0.0      0.0     0.0    0.0       1.0   
300                  600             0.0      0.0     0.0    0.0       0.0   

                                 War  Western  
Film                 Body_Count                
24 Hour Party People 7           0.0      0.0  
28 Days Later        53          0.0      0.0  
28 Weeks Later       212         0.0      0.0  
30 Days of Night     67          0.0      0.0  
300                  600         1.0      0.0
```

To remove `Film` and `Body_Count` from the `index`, use

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you! One more thing i need to do is make the data from body count and genres into a matrix, so i can perform some regression tasks. But the body count seems to be an index. Do you know how I could deal with that?

Comment: Use .reset_index() on the result.

Comment: I have one last problem - after processing my data, the dataframe shrinked from 545 to 542 rows, do you know what could have caused that?

Comment: Missing data, like 3 movies have no genre info?

Comment: That's right, sorry, I'm new to programming, as you may see :) Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [pandas.get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'genre': ['action', 'thriller', 'drama'], 'kills':[50,100,150]})
print(df)
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['genre'])
df = pd.concat([df,dummies], axis=1)
df = df.drop('genre',1)
print(df)

## -- End pasted text --
      genre  kills
0    action     50
1  thriller    100
2     drama    150
   kills  action  drama  thriller
0     50     1.0    0.0       0.0
1    100     0.0    0.0       1.0
2    150     0.0    1.0       0.0
```